# I/O error and read only file issue

Tags: updates, dpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded Ubuntu because I need to run linux software (MUMmer, a bioinformatics tool) on my PC. Im trying to follow this websites instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment#set-up-your-linux-user-info and I get to the step where I need to update and upgrade packages and I have to type:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

and I get these errors: [first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSHr.png)

I tried googling it and it said to try:

`sudo apt-get update`

but when I did, I got these errors:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.waoP04 for passing config to apt-key
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_Release - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Error!
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.Auv1Lz - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.bTmzQz - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.x6Yb4z - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/.apt-acquire-privs-test.14iUqA - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.waoP04 for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_InRelease - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-updates_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_Release - PrepareFiles (30: Read-only file system)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)
E: Unable to mkstemp /tmp/clearsigned.message.osv9ux - GetTempFile (30: Read-only file system)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

and it said to try

`sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates`

but I got this error:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

after running
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

I get this error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
```

I tried looking for solutions but I have no idea what all this is or means, unfortunately. I don't know what this /var/lib/dkkg directory is or where it is or what I need to do.

I tried ignoring this error and moving on to the other steps, for downloading anaconda, which I need to then download biocondna
but then I get this error:

```
wget: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5: cannot read file data: Input/output error
```

Any help would be much appreciated because I'm starting to dispair. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The output of powershell.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qLHj.png)

EDIT NUMBER 2 :
Errors when installing anaconda, more RO stuff.:

```
/home/noor/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/noor/anaconda3] >>>
PREFIX=/home/noor/anaconda3
installing: python-3.7.0-hc3d631a_0 ...
Python 3.7.0
installing: blas-1.0-mkl ...
installing: ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0 ...
installing: conda-env-2.6.0-1 ...
installing: intel-openmp-2019.0-118 ...
installing: libgcc-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1 ...
installing: libgfortran-ng-7.3.0-hdf63c60_0 ...
installing: libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1 ...
installing: bzip2-1.0.6-h14c3975_5 ...
installing: expat-2.2.6-he6710b0_0 ...
installing: fribidi-1.0.5-h7b6447c_0 ...
installing: gmp-6.1.2-h6c8ec71_1 ...
installing: graphite2-1.3.12-h23475e2_2 ...
installing: icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1 ...
installing: jbig-2.1-hdba287a_0 ...
installing: jpeg-9b-h024ee3a_2 ...
installing: libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4 ...
installing: libsodium-1.0.16-h1bed415_0 ...
installing: libtool-2.4.6-h544aabb_3 ...
installing: libuuid-1.0.3-h1bed415_2 ...
installing: libxcb-1.13-h1bed415_1 ...
installing: lzo-2.10-h49e0be7_2 ...
installing: mkl-2019.0-118 ...
tar: lib/libmkl_vml_avx512.so: Wrote only 1536 of 10240 bytes
tar: lib/libmkl_vml_avx512.so: Cannot utime: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_vml_avx2.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_vml_avx.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_vml_avx512_mic.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_sequential.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_gnu_thread.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_tbb_thread.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_pgi_thread.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_def.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_mc.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_mc3.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_avx.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_avx2.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_avx512.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_core.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: lib/libmkl_avx512_mic.so: Cannot open: Read-only file system
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134637/discussion-on-question-by-noor-i-o-error-and-read-only-file-issue).

Comment: Thanks @Mitch - Certainly wanted to move it earlier, but lack of OP rep didn't make it possible until now.

Answer (score 6):

We established in comments and chat that you ran out of disk space on the Windows drive where WSL is installed.  This caused WSL to mark the drive as read-only to Ubuntu, masking the true problem.

Once this happens, it's not possible to recover from it *from Ubuntu*.  The virtual disk that WSL2 uses will *grow* when files are added to it, but it does not automatically *shrink* when data is removed.  There are workarounds, but I think you'd need free disk space in order to use them anyway.

So since this is a freshly (re)installed Ubuntu and you've already removed a previous version, I'm going to suggest we start with uninstalling all current WSL instances (Ubuntu and Ubuntu 20.04).  That will recover at least some space for *Windows* to function properly, as you might start seeing errors there as well.

However, as you are fairly low on disk space, this clearly isn't going to be enough.  You'll need to free up some space on the Windows side before attempting to reinstall WSL/Ubuntu and Anaconda.

I'd recommend 4GB if you can get that much.  A base WSL/Ubuntu install takes around 1.7GB iirc.  Then you'll need to do updates, the Anaconda install, and presumably data.  And Windows is going to want some free disk space for its purposes as well.  You can *probably* make it work with 3GB, but I'd really try for 4 if you can.

I'm kind of surprised that Windows didn't pop up the "low disk space" warning and offer to run the Disk Cleanup option, but at least start there.  From the Start menu, type "Disk Cleanup" and see how much space you can recover.  Dang - I have 27GB right there myself!  Hopefully you'll be as lucky!

---

Okay, continuing this since you just don't have much space to reclaim on `C:`, but you do seem to have more space on your `D:` drive.

Start by removing both existing WSL distributions if you haven't already.  That should give you at least enough space to start.

Then reinstall "Ubuntu" as you did before.  Launch it one time to create your user/password, then exit it.  We've established that you should have at least enough disk space on `C:` to do that.

Now, go to PowerShell:

```
# Modify this first line if you'd like to use a different location
$WSL_BASE = "D:\WSL" 
mkdir "$WSL_BASE\instances\Ubuntu"
mkdir "$WSL_BASE\images"
cd "$WSL_BASE"

wsl --export Ubuntu "$WSL_BASE\images\ubuntu.tar"
# The "UbuntuD" in the next line can be whatever you want to name it
wsl --import UbuntuD "$WSL_BASE\instances\Ubuntu" "$WSL_BASE\images\ubuntu.tar" --version 2
wsl ~ -d UbuntuD
```

You should now be in a the UbuntuD that we installed on the `D:` drive.  You should be root, since WSL doesn't "remember" your default username when `--import`'ing.   We can set it with the following:

Important - The following code block is a multi-line command and most be run all at once (don't run line-by-line as suggested with the others.

Also important - Modify the "username" in this line before pasting the following:

```sh
sudo sh -c "( cat << EOF
[user]
default=username
EOF
) > /etc/wsl.conf"
```

`exit` to return to PowerShell.  Then `wsl --terminate UbuntuD` from PowerShell.

From PowerShell:

```
wsl --set-default UbuntuD
wsl ~
```

Try your `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and install Anaconda again.

Hopefully that gives you the space you need.

Now uninstall "Ubuntu" so that you reclaim the space from `C:`.

Note that your very low disk space on `C:` is going to continue to be a major problem for other Windows apps, I would expect, but at least not for WSL at this point.

Also recommend installing Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store.  It will pick up your new WSL distribution and automatically create a profile for it.

Comment: Hello! I cannot thank you enough for taking the time to help me. The thing is I do have a lot of disk space, like 300GB , on my D disk, not the C one. For some reason the engineer split them into two when I upgraded my PC from HDD to an SSD. I tried installing the WSL and Ubuntu thing on the D disk but I didn't understand the steps. I'm gonna try to uninstall everything and see how it goes. If you have any tips on how I could install things to my D drive that would be great. Thanks again! I'll update you when I can.

Comment: @NOOR Sure - We can do the move to the D drive.  I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Ok, I've "scripted" it out so that the commands for moving should work.  I do recommend copying/pasting each of them one-by-one to make sure they work, though.